# Login to Splashscreen to Main Activity android

Tags: android

i got stuck here in manifest . i have login activity,  splash screen activty and main activity . already can run but only login activity first then splash screen. main activity not showing up.

thanks for your advice

This is my apps flow. Login activity > Splashscreen > Main activity

Comment: pls make sure your are using splash screen as the launcher activity in manifest

Comment: but in my task. login is set first as launcer and then go to splashscreen and then to main activity i got confuse here

Comment: what is ur required flow,can u explain in detail

Comment: this is the flow. Login activity > Splashscreen > Main activity .

Comment: may be u have not called an intent to start main activity from splash activity

Comment: nah i dont how to call. can u give me the clue?

Comment: oh thanks already work. i try intent from splash to main acitivty thanks

Comment: please show us your code. show we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic Android. At the very minimum, you need to declare in your manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.yourpackage.com.LoginActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
  android:name="com.yourpackage.com.SplashActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.yourpackage.com.LoginActivity" />
</activity>

<activity
  android:name="com.yourpackage.com.MainActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.yourpackage.com.SplashActivity" />
</activity>
```

one is the launched activity (Login), the other ones declare their parent activity; then on each activity, at the right time you need to start the next activity, respectively like this:

```
// this call happens in LoginActivity
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
// this call happens in SplashActivity
startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
```

that's all you need for this. Note: there are better approaches for the splash screen, but I think for now this will be enough for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declared activities correctly in Manifest? It should be like that.

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

`SplashActivity` must be the first activity launched as you open your app.Then it depends on whether user logined before or not to jump to `MainActivity` or `LoginActivity`.

```
 boolean loginedBefore = hasLogined();//may be a blocking operationø
    if (loginedBefore) {//logined before
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {// first launch
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

code above is in the `onCreate` method in `SplashActivity.java`.

Comment: Sorry im already edit my question. 
in my case login activity is should first and then go to splashscreen activity then go to main acvitiy .